# How to call REC Registery API and store returned JSONs into some kind of database

Tags: javascript, json, api, lamp

I'd like to break this into smaller, tighter questions but I don't know what I don't know enough to do that yet. So hopefully a can get specific answers to help do that.

The **scope** of the solution requires receiving & parsing a lot of records, 2013 had ~17 million certificate(s) transactions while I'm only interested in very small subsets of the order 40,000 records.

**In pseudo code:**

- iterate dates(thisDate)

  - send message to API for thisDate
  - receive JSONS as todaysRecords
  - examine todaysRecords to look for whatever criteria match inside the structure
  - append a subset of todaysRecords to recordsOut
- save recordsOut to a SQL/CSV file.

There's a large database of Renewable Energy Certificates for the use under the [Australian Government RET Scheme](http://www.cleanenergyregulator.gov.au/RET/Pages/default.aspx) called the [REC Registery](https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/public/lgc-register) and as well as the web interface linked to [here](https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/public/lgc-register), there is an API provided that has a simple call logic as follows

`http://rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/api/public-register/certificate-actions?date=<user provided date>` where:

- The date part of the URL should be provided by the user
- Date format should be YYYY-MM-DD (no angle brackets & 1 date limit)

A JSON is returned (with potentially 100,000s of records on each day).

The API documentation (13pp PDF) is [here](http://www.cleanenergyregulator.gov.au/DocumentAssets/Documents/REC%20Registry%20API%20specifications.pdf), but it mainly goes into explaining the elements of the returned structure which is less relevant to my question. Includes two sample JSON responses.

While I know some Javascript (mostly not in a web context) I'm not sure how send this message within a script and figure I'd need to do it server side to be able to process (filter) the returned information and then save the records I'm interested in. I'll have no issue parsing the JSON (if i can use JS) and copying the objects I wish to save I'm not sure where to even start doing this. Do I need a LAMP setup to do this (or MAMP since I'm on OS X) or is there a more light-weight JS way I can execute this. I've never known how to save file from within web-browser JS, I thought it was banned for security reasons but I guess theres ways and means.

If i can rewrite this question to be more clear and effective in soliciting an answer I'm happy for edits to question also.

I guess maybe I'm after some boilerplate code for calling a simple API like this and the stack or application context in which I need to do it. I realise there's potential several ways to execute this but looking for most straightforward for someone with JS knowledge and not much PHP/Python experience (but willing to learn what it takes).

Easy right?

Comment: To clarify, you want to call this from a web page and you just need to know how to call the service with the date?

Comment: doesn't have to be from within a web page. I'm not offering it as a public service it's just that this is the only to download the data for analysis in whatever environment I decide to do so. manual screen scrapping is not an option because the web interface returns incomplete records (otherwise I'd have gone that route).

Comment: "I'll have no issue parsing the JSON (if i can use JS) and copying the objects I wish to save"  
Q if you want to ask questions, how are you going to do it? My suggestion is as you read the data, parse it and import into a database. This means you will have to set up a DB of some sort ( could be anything rom sqlite to Postgres). This allows you to write queries in SQL to answer those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to point you in the right direction.

## Requirements

If the language of choice is Javascript, you'll need to install [**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org/). No server whatsoever needed.

Same is valid for PHP or Python or whatever. No apache needed, just the lang int.

## Running a script with node

Create a `file.js` somewhere. To run it, you'll just need to type (in the console) `node file.js` (in the directory the file lives in.

## Getting the onfo from the REC Webservice

Here's an example of a GET request:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    host: 'rec-registry.gov.au',
    port: 443,
    path: '/rec-registry/app/api/public-register/certificate-actions?date=2015-06-03'
};
var jsonstr = '';

var request = https.get(options, function(response) {
  process.stdout.write("downloading data...");
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    process.stdout.write(".");
    jsonstr += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    process.stdout.write("DONE!");
    console.log(' ');
    console.log('Writing to file...');
    fs.writeFile("data.json", jsonstr, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('Error saving file'); 
      }
    console.log('The file was saved!');
    });
  });
})

request.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('Error downloading file: ' + e.message);
});
```

## Transforming a json string into an object/array

use `JSON.parse`

## Parsing the data

> examine todaysRecords to look for whatever criteria match inside the structure

Can't help you there, but should be relatively straightforward to look for the correct object properties.

**NOTE:** Basically, what you get from the request is a string. You then parse that string with

```
var foo = JSON.parse(jsonstr)
```

In this case `foo` is an object. The results "certificates" are actually inside the property `result`, which is an array

```
var results = foo.result;
```

In this example the array contains about 1700 records and the structure of a certificate is something like this:

```
"actionType": "STC created",
"completedTime": "2015-06-02T21:51:26.955Z",
"certificateRanges": [{
  "certificateType": "STC",
  "registeredPersonNumber": 10894,
  "accreditationCode": "PVD2259359",
  "generationYear": 2015,
  "generationState": "QLD",
  "startSerialNumber": 1,
  "endSerialNumber": 72,
  "fuelSource": "S.G.U. - solar (deemed)",
  "ownerAccount": "Solargain PV Pty Ltd",
  "ownerAccountId": 25782,
  "status": "Pending audit"
}]
```

So, to access, for instance, the "ownerAccount" of the first "certificateRanges" of the first "certificate" you would do:

```
var results = JSON.parse(jsonstr).result;

var ownerAccount = results[0].certificateRanges[0].ownerAccount;
```

## Creating a csv

The best way is to create an abstract structure (that meets your needs) and convert it to a csv.

There's a good npm library called [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) that can help you there

Example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var json2csv = require('json2csv'); 
var fields = ['car', 'price', 'color']; // csv titles
var myCars = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": 40000,
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": 35000,
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": 60000,
    "color": "green"
  }
];

json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });
});
```

If you wish to append instead of writing to a new file you can use

```
fs.appendFile('file.csv', csv, function (err) { });
```

Comment: done. btw what is the fs in fs.writefile('…) referring to?

Comment: sorry forgot the import `var fs = require('fs');`

Comment: is 'fs' a JS library I need to DL? searching npm, it seems like it's included in node.js library maybe? there's other fs-foo libraries but no 'fs' straight

Comment: fs is included in node

Comment: Is your 'getting the info' code (first script) essentially complete to pull data? when I add the line "console.log(jsonstr);" node says it's undefined'. I tried calling the http.request script by assigning it to a variable "callREC = http.request(…" then "response = callREC" and both response and jsonstr return false. I guess jsonstr is out of scope in the main script… confused about #REST

Comment: See my edited answer. I didn't test with that webservice of yours because the response was very big and I was on 4G. However, the connection requires https. I've tested the code and it's working now

Comment: Cheers Tivie — I do believe we can award the tick. My browser was redirecting to https without me noticing. REC API docs need updating.

Comment: And you anticipated my next questions… how to do std.out and write a JSON file.

Comment: when I log jsonstr.length it's like 1152908. And if I loop thru as in jsonstr[n] I get one char per element. So i figured it's a string not a JS object so then I tried var myjsonobj = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
 console.log(myjsonobj.length); and I am told myjsonobj is undefined. I am trying to find a way to output items in the JSON to the console as a debug tool so I can write the code to filter and re-organise into a flat file that will save to CSV (there's multiple certificate objects within each transaction sometimes plus there's the top level "status" and "result" objects I need to lose. new Q?

Comment: also I tried eval(jsonstr) and it threw exception at the first colon (':').

Comment: I copy pasted the JSON file into http://jsonlint.com/ and it validates (and pretty prints yay). so JSON.parse(jsonstr) should work right?

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil A javascript object does not have a length property. see example: https://jsfiddle.net/tivie/tr6p79a8/

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Check my edited answer, after "Parsing the data"

Comment: hey thanks again. I was trying var results = JSON.parse(jsonstr.result); kind of things <duh!/>

Comment: press F12 on Chrome or Firefox and choose console

Comment: next thing Teach :-) so i started writing some more code inside the request = http.get(…) function (all good) but it was getting messy so I moved the additional code to below your script. I repeated the results = JSON.parse(jsonstr) line again in case it was scope limited inside the request function. my non-existent knowledge of node.js and asynchronous functions tells me that single line causing an 'undefined:0' error is bc it's executing before request function has finished or has been allowed to start. feel free to point me to good docs… I did look at node.js docs but heavy going…

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil it's async, so the code inside response.on(...) gets called whenever the event is triggered. You can, however, wrap the code with a function and call that function inside the event callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83494/discussion-between-wide-eyed-pupil-and-tivie).